# Pop up warning in center of browser when value exceeds number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a page pulling SNMP data (using php) and then displaying it via HTML and color coding the values. I'd like to add a pop up alert when value exceeds a specific number.

I have tried various jquery options to make this happen but its not working.

PHP part to obtain value:

```
<?php
$valueis = snmp2_get("IPADDRESS", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42", 1000000, 0);
?>
```

HTML part:

```
<html>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="20">
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table_fid td.mynumber').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() <= '16' ) {
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        }
        if ($(this).text() > '16' ) {
            $(this).addClass('green');
        }
   });
});

<DIV style="position: absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width:10px; height:10px"><table id="table_fid">
<td class="mynumber"><a href=http://mywebsite.com><?php echo $valueis?></a></td></tr>
</table></DIV>
```

This works great.

However I want it that when value is higher than 16, it also shows a pop up window in the browser as an alert.  I've tried to incorporate the guide in this page to auto trigger but with no luck: https://html-online.com/articles/simple-popup-box/.  The pop up window in this page is exactly how I wish mine to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This solution is for MODERN browsers, supporting rgba(). Older browsers require some more advanced CSS.*

You should ideally be accessing the PHP value through AJAX, but you can hardcode the PHP value(s) in the JS section to make things easier, and then insert the value(s) into the DOM object(s) (`td.mynumber`).

Your example only shows one row of data... but considering you used an $.each() iterator, you may be simplifying a solution for multiple rows?

For a single row:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
//first assign the PHP value
var the_value = <?php echo $valueis?>; //notice NO quotes! because this is numeric!

//now you can use 'the_value' instead of reading from the DOM object
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table_fid td.mynumber').each(function(){
        //assign the_value to the DOM object
        $(this).children().text(the_value);

        //add classes based on the_value
        if (the_value <= 16 ) {//the_value is NUMERIC - no quotes!
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        }

        else {//you don't need another 'if' here, value must be higher than 16
            $(this).addClass('green');
            //show overlay
            $('#overlay').show()// changes display: none to block
        }
   });
});

function closeOverlay () {
    $('#overlay').hide()// changes display: block to none
}
</script>
<style>
*,*:before,*:after{/*best practice, reset box-sizing to include borders and padding in width!*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{/*best practice, reset body container values*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#table-container{
    position: absolute; 
    top:10px; 
    left:10px; 
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    z-index: 1; /*Make this render as the bottom layer*/
}
#overlay{
    display: none; /* default state hidden */
    position: fixed; /* does not move */
    top: 0;/* place at top */
    left: 0;/*place at left */
    height: 100%;/* full height of container */
    width: 100%;/* full width of container */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);/* semi-transparent black background */
    z-index: 2;/*Make this render ABOVE the bottom layer, because 2 is greater than 1!*/
}

#overlay-x{
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 16px;/*border-radius of HALF height makes this a circle!*/
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    background: white;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    /* now position this white circle */
    position: absolute;/* absolutely positioned */
    top: 0; /*place at top */
    right: 0;/*place at right*/
    margin-top: -10px;/*pull UP 10px*/
    margin-right: -10px;/*pull RIGHT 10px*/
    cursor: pointer;/*show pointer on hover to make it LOOK clickable*/
}

/* fixed-size  */
#overlay-message-container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    /* this is how you center position fixed-size */
    position: absolute;/* absolutely positioned */
    top: 50%; /* place in absolute center of container height */
    left: 50%;/* place in absolute center of container width */
    margin-top: -100px; /* pull exactly HALF of the HEIGHT UPward*/
    margin-left: -150px; /* pull exactly HALF of the WIDTH LEFTward*/
    padding: 80px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);/*drop shadow effect*/
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table-container"><!--moved styles to HEAD-->
    <table id="table_fid">
      <tr>
        <td class="mynumber"><a href="http://mywebsite.com"><!--don't need PHP here, value is assigned by JS!--></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="overlay"><!--the overlay-->
    <div id="overlay-message-container"><!--the message container-->
        <div id="overlay-x" onclick="closeOverlay()">X</div><!--the X to close the window-->
        <div id="overlay-message">This is the message inside the overlay!</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have multiple rows being printed, you'd assign an array of JS values:

```
<script>
//first assign the PHP values - assuming 4 values
var the_values = [
  <?php echo $valueis_1?>, //this is a list of value, use commas
  <?php echo $valueis_2?>,
  <?php echo $valueis_3?>,
  <?php echo $valueis_4?>
] 

//now you can use the_values instead of reading from the DOM object
//Note: $.each() is passed an 'index' value which returns the current loop iteration; you can use this to assign array values
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table_fid td.mynumber').each(function(index){//note 'index'!
        //assign the_value to the DOM object
        $(this).text(the_values[index]);

        //add classes based on the_values[index]
        if (the_values[index] <= 16 ) {//the_values[index] is NUMERIC - no quotes!
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        }

        else {//you don't need another 'if' here, value must be higher than 16
            $(this).addClass('green');
            //show overlay - doesn't matter if it's already showing!
            $('#overlay-message').show()
        }
   });
});
</script>
```

And then in your HTML, you'd need the 4 rows added:

```
<div id="table-container"><!--moved styles to HEAD-->
    <table id="table_fid">
      <tr>
        <td class="mynumber"><a href="http://mywebsite.com"><!--don't need PHP here, value is assigned by JS!--></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mynumber"><a href="http://mywebsite.com"><!--don't need PHP here, value is assigned by JS!--></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mynumber"><a href="http://mywebsite.com"><!--don't need PHP here, value is assigned by JS!--></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mynumber"><a href="http://mywebsite.com"><!--don't need PHP here, value is assigned by JS!--></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Proof here:
https://codepen.io/remedio/pen/pozbdLY

This is a simplified answer for a FIXED-SIZE container. There is some cool stuff you can do with pseudo-elements and inline-blocks to make dynamic sized elements centered....

Comment: Thanks! Pointed me in the right direction! It's now working